# Does .Include method hit the database in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am testing the Linq query below. And I'm checking the log to see if there is a database hit:

```
var productEntities = _context.Set<Product>()
                .Include(p => p.OrderItems)
                .Include(p => p.OrderItems.Select(oi => oi.Order))
                .Include(p => p.OrderItems.Select(oi => oi.Order.Client));

            Console.WriteLine(productEntities.Count());
```

Whether I comment out the call to Count() or not, the log shows this same output:

> ```
> Opened connection at 8/20/2016 3:32:53 PM -04:00
> ```
>
> SELECT Count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t WHERE
>   t.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + t.TABLE_NAME IN
>   ('dbo.AccountRecords','dbo.Products','dbo.Doughs','dbo.OrderItems','dbo.Orders','dbo.Clients','dbo.ShippingInformations','dbo.OrderSpecialClients','dbo.OrderSpecialProducts','dbo.Taxes','dbo.FixedOrders','dbo.FixedOrderItems','dbo.OrderSubstitutions','dbo.OrderPerformanceLog')
>       OR t.TABLE_NAME = 'EdmMetadata'
>   -- Executing at 8/20/2016 3:32:53 PM -04:00
>   -- Completed in 2 ms with result: 14
>
> Closed connection at 8/20/2016 3:32:53 PM -04:00 Opened connection at
>   8/20/2016 3:32:53 PM -04:00 SELECT
>       [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
>       FROM ( SELECT
>           COUNT(1) AS [A1]
>           FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
>           WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = @p__linq__0
>       )  AS [GroupBy1]
>   -- p__linq__0: 'Arhoma.Core.Data.ArhomaContext' (Type = String, Size = 4000)
>   -- Executing at 8/20/2016 3:32:53 PM -04:00
>   -- Failed in 51 ms with error: Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'.
>
> Closed connection at 8/20/2016 3:32:53 PM -04:00 Opened connection at
>   8/20/2016 3:32:53 PM -04:00 SELECT
>       [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
>       FROM ( SELECT
>           COUNT(1) AS [A1]
>           FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
>       )  AS [GroupBy1]
>   -- Executing at 8/20/2016 3:32:53 PM -04:00
>   -- Failed in 36 ms with error: Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'.
>
> Closed connection at 8/20/2016 3:32:53 PM -04:00 Opened connection at
>   8/20/2016 3:32:53 PM -04:00 SELECT
>       [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
>       FROM ( SELECT
>           COUNT(1) AS [A1]
>           FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
>       )  AS [GroupBy1]
>   -- Executing at 8/20/2016 3:32:53 PM -04:00
>   -- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> Closed connection at 8/20/2016 3:32:53 PM -04:00 299

My question: Why does it hit the database? I thought the hit is made when I add a .ToList() or something or when it calls a .Count()? But it still hits the database even when I remove the call to Count(). So now I'm thinking, is it the .Include that forces a database hit?

Comment: without the Count() call, the database should not be hit. and Include cannot force query execution, it is vital for the query creation itself. there must've been something else. you can try disposing your context after the Include() calls and see where the exception is thrown (which is where the query is executed)

Answer (score 3):

All these `MigrationHistory` related queries run only once, the very first time your code connects to the database. The EF just tries to verify if the database needs to be upgraded to a newer version.

To confirm that, try any meaningful query **before** the one you presented so that the query with `Include`s is the second one. You will see all this versioning noise, then your first query and then nothing, as `Include` itself is not retrieving anything.

Comment: Ok, you are right, but partially. What about the last one which querying the `Products`? Why it happens?

Comment: Because you are doing 'productEntities.Count()' which executes a SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Products.